# Create VSTS Merge report

Tags: tfs, merge, azure-devops, tfvc

We are using VSTS/TFS for source code control. We sometimes have to Merge branches. When a conflict rises between files we get the Source, the Target, and the proposed new file. What I am looking for is a Merge report which shows this for all files merged, even the files that do not have conflicts.

Does anyone know if this is possible in VSTS?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of possible... After performing the merge, before resolving any conflicts you can run `tf folderdiff` to get all changed files and their status. Then use `tf diff` to get the differences between the source and target.

Or you can use the Visual studio client object model to query all of the information.

There is no built-in Visual Studio wizard or option to just export a report.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how can I run the commands in VSTS? Or is VS2017?

Comment: This is from a developer command prompt on a machine where visual studio is installed.

Comment: I haven't been able to get the command to work. I am getting Access Denied error when using the command line

Comment: How did you use the command? Can you share it? Are you able to access the VSTS from browser? The command should look like: `tf folderdiff D:\Workspace\VSTS\TestCase\TestCaseProject-branch $/TestCase/TestCaseProject-branch /collection:https://xxx.visualstudio.com /login:username,[password]`